# Resolve Powershell Script to Click On Google Result

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

i have powershell script to find a website on google result and click on website link

```
$IE = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$IE.navigate("https://www.google.com/search?q=%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C+%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3&oq=%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C")
$IE.visible=$true

while ($IE.busy) {sleep  10}

$Link = ($html.Links |Where-Object { $_.class -eq 'https://khabarfarsi.com' }) |Select-Object -ExpandProperty href
$Link = ($HTML.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("a") | Where {$_.className -eq 'https://khabarfarsi.com'}).InnerHTML
$Link = @($IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -like 'https://khabarfarsi.com'})[0]
if ($Link -eq $null){ $Link = $IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | ? {$_.InnerHTML -like 'https://khabarfarsi.com'} }
if ($Link -eq $null){$ie.quit(); Break}
$Link.click()
```

I have a number of beginner trainees who often have trouble doing this. I want to create a script that they don't need to do manually.

Thank you for accompanying me in doing this

Thanks

Regards

Comment: Do you mean your script is not able to click on that link and the IE browser gets closed? Can you please explain that you already know the link for the site you want to click so why don't you directly navigate the IE browser to that link? Is there any specific purpose for searching it via Google? Let us know about that. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help
Yes, unfortunately the script does not find the desired link on the Internet Explorer to click on it and in powershell "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"
Yes, we know the address of the link to be clicked
We work on the topic every day. With this method, there is no need to open the content. I don't need to go to all users' desks.
I put two variables in this script, and by changing these variables, this script will read the variables from my system, and the script will continue to run.
Thank you for guiding me in this regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working script that can find and click the link.

```
$ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://www.google.com/search?q=%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B2%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C+%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3&oq=%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1%DA%AF%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C")
while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.href -eq 'https://khabarfarsi.com/w/farsnews.com'}
$link.click()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: If you think that the modified script that I have provided in my previous answer can help to fix your issue then I suggest you can accept that suggestion as an answer to this question. It can help other community members in similar kinds of issues in the future. If you have any further questions please let us know about it. Thanks for your understanding. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers